# Ktor: Serialize/Deserialize JSON with List as root in Multiplatform

Tags: json, serialization, kotlin, ktor, kotlin-multiplatform

How can we use kotlin.serialize with Ktor's HttpClient to deserialize/serialize JSON with lists as root?  I am creating the HttpClient as follows:

```
HttpClient {
       install(JsonFeature) {
           serializer = KotlinxSerializer().apply {
               setMapper(MyClass::class, MyClass.serializer())
               setMapper(AnotherClass::class, AnotherClass.serializer())
           }
       }
       install(ExpectSuccess)
   }
```

Appears I need to setMapper for List, however that is not possible with generics.  I see I can get the serializer for it with MyClass.serializer().list, but registering it to deserialize/serialize on http requests is not straight forward.  Anyone know of a good solution?

Comment: See that there's a `KotlinxSerializer.registerList()` ....tried that but still getting "Can't locate argument-less serializer for class kotlin.collections.List. For generic classes, such as lists, please provide serializer explicitly." error

Comment: Some possibly related discussion on this in following as well (though haven't figured out yet how to apply this when using `HttpClient` - https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization/issues/179

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Update with ktor 1.3.0:**

Now you're able to receive default collections(such a list) from the client directly:

```
@Serializable
data class User(val id: Int)

val response: List<User> = client.get(...)
// or client.get<List<User>>(...)
```

**Before ktor 1.3.0:**

There is no way to (de)serialize such JSON in the kotlinx.serialization yet.

For serialization you could try something like this:

```
fun serializer(data: Any) = if (data is List<*>) {
   if (data is EmptyList) String::class.serializer().list // any class with serializer 
   else data.first()::class.serializer().list
} else data.serializer()
```

And there are no known ways to get the list deserializer.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  Something like this worked for me until.

Comment: Btw we will introduce `typeOf` feature support in 1.3.0.

Comment: @Leonid now that 1.3.0 is available could you edit this answer to use `typeOf`? Thanks!

Comment: client.get was gold for me.

Answer (score 10):

You can write wrapper and custom serializer:

```
@Serializable
class MyClassList(
    val items: List<MyClass>
) {

    @Serializer(MyClassList::class)
    companion object : KSerializer<MyClassList> {

        override val descriptor = StringDescriptor.withName("MyClassList")

        override fun serialize(output: Encoder, obj: MyClassList) {
            MyClass.serializer().list.serialize(output, obj.items)
        }

        override fun deserialize(input: Decoder): MyClassList {
            return MyClassList(MyClass.serializer().list.deserialize(input))
        }
    }
}
```

Register it:

```
HttpClient {
    install(JsonFeature) {
        serializer = KotlinxSerializer().apply {
            setMapper(MyClassList::class, MyClassList.serializer())
        }
    }
}
```

And use:

```
suspend fun fetchItems(): List<MyClass> {
    return client.get<MyClassList>(URL).items
}
```

Comment: Nice solution, actually we don't need to register it at step 2, Ktor will automatically apply the MyClassList.serializer()

Comment: I actually do need to register, otherwise, it only works on debugging (progard breaks it somehow)

Comment: Defeats the purpose of having a generic though. Hope this gets a better solution soon

Answer (score 5):

This is more of a workaround but after stepping through `KotlinxSerializer` code I couldn't see any other way round it.  If you look at `KotlinxSerializer.read()` for example you can see it tries to look up a `mapper` based on `type` but in this case it's just a `kotlin.collections.List` and doesn't resolve.  I had tried calling something like `setListMapper(MyClass::class, MyClass.serializer())` but this only works for serialization (using by `lookupSerializerByData` method in `write`)

```
override suspend fun read(type: TypeInfo, response: HttpResponse): Any {
    val mapper = lookupSerializerByType(type.type)
    val text = response.readText()

    @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
    return json.parse(mapper as KSerializer<Any>, text)
}
```

So, what I ended up doing was something like (note the `serializer().list` call)

```
suspend fun fetchBusStops(): List<BusStop> {
    val jsonArrayString = client.get<String> {
        url("$baseUrl/stops.json")
    }

    return JSON.nonstrict.parse(BusStop.serializer().list, jsonArrayString)
}
```

Not ideal and obviously doesn't make use of `JsonFeature`.

Answer (score 0):

I happened to have the same problem on Kotlin/JS, and managed to fix it this way:

```
private val client = HttpClient(Js) {
  install(JsonFeature) {
    serializer = KotlinxSerializer().apply {
      register(User.serializer().list)
    }
  }
}
...
private suspend fun fetchUsers(): Sequence<User> =
    client.get<List<User>> {
      url("$baseUrl/users")
    }.asSequence()
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Works only if you register only one list serializer. When there are more, KotlinxSerializer.lookupSerializerByType() doesn't distinguish between them and picks unpredictably.